# Lean golf: List Game Lv2 (is_in_append, is_in_rev)

Tags: code-golf, lean

The title is an homage of the [Natural Number Game](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/natural_number_game/), which is a nice interactive tutorial into proving certain properties of natural numbers in Lean.

---

The definitions used in [Lv1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/236182/78410) will be reused here. I've done some improvements:

- Now it starts with `import tactic`, which means you can freely use powerful mathlib tactics.
- I noticed that I can define the general list notation `[a, b, ..., z]` without problems.

```
import tactic
universe u
variables {A : Type u}
namespace mylist

inductive list (T : Type u) : Type u
| nil : list
| cons : T → list → list

infixr ` :: `:67 := list.cons
notation `[]` := list.nil
notation `[` l:(foldr `, ` (h t, list.cons h t) list.nil `]`) := l

def append : list A → list A → list A
| [] t := t
| (h :: s) t := h :: (append s t)
instance : has_append (list A) := ⟨@append A⟩

@[simp] lemma nil_append (s : list A) : [] ++ s = s := rfl
@[simp] lemma cons_append (x : A) (s t : list A) : (x :: s) ++ t = x :: (s ++ t) := rfl

@[simp] def rev : list A → list A
| [] := []
| (h :: t) := rev t ++ [h]
```

Now, here's a new definition we will use from now on: a membership relationship between an element and a list. It is defined recursively using two cases: A value `x` is in a list `l` if

- `x` is the head of `l`, or
- `x` is in the tail of `l`.

```
inductive is_in : A → list A → Prop
| in_hd {x : A} {l : list A} : is_in x (x :: l)
| in_tl {x y : A} {l : list A} : is_in x l → is_in x (y :: l)
open is_in
```

Now your task is to prove the following two statements: (think of these as parts of a chapter, sharing a few lemmas)

- `is_in_append`: `x` appears in `l1 ++ l2` if and only if `x` appears in `l1` or `x` appears in `l2`.
- `is_in_rev`: if `x` appears in `l`, `x` appears in `rev l`.

```
theorem is_in_append : ∀ (x : A) (l1 l2 : list A), is_in x (l1 ++ l2) ↔ is_in x l1 \/ is_in x l2 := sorry
theorem is_in_rev : ∀ (x : A) (l : list A), is_in x l → is_in x (rev l) := sorry
```

You can change the name of each statement and golf its definition, as long as its type is correct. [Any kind of sidestepping is not allowed.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23938/78410) Due to the nature of this challenge, adding imports is also not allowed (i.e. no mathlib, except for tactics).

The entire boilerplate is provided [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20tactic%0Auniverse%20u%0Avariables%20%7BA%20%3A%20Type%20u%7D%0Anamespace%20mylist%0A%0Ainductive%20list%20%28T%20%3A%20Type%20u%29%20%3A%20Type%20u%0A%7C%20nil%20%3A%20list%0A%7C%20cons%20%3A%20T%20%E2%86%92%20list%20%E2%86%92%20list%0A%0Ainfixr%20%60%20%3A%3A%20%60%3A67%20%3A%3D%20list.cons%0Anotation%20%60%5B%5D%60%20%3A%3D%20list.nil%0Anotation%20%60%5B%60%20l%3A%28foldr%20%60%2C%20%60%20%28h%20t%2C%20list.cons%20h%20t%29%20list.nil%20%60%5D%60%29%20%3A%3D%20l%0A%0Adef%20append%20%3A%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%0A%7C%20%5B%5D%20t%20%3A%3D%20t%0A%7C%20%28h%20%3A%3A%20s%29%20t%20%3A%3D%20h%20%3A%3A%20%28append%20s%20t%29%0Ainstance%20%3A%20has_append%20%28list%20A%29%20%3A%3D%20%E2%9F%A8%40append%20A%E2%9F%A9%0A%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20lemma%20nil_append%20%28s%20%3A%20list%20A%29%20%3A%20%5B%5D%20%2B%2B%20s%20%3D%20s%20%3A%3D%20rfl%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20lemma%20cons_append%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28s%20t%20%3A%20list%20A%29%20%3A%20%28x%20%3A%3A%20s%29%20%2B%2B%20t%20%3D%20x%20%3A%3A%20%28s%20%2B%2B%20t%29%20%3A%3D%20rfl%0A%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20def%20rev%20%3A%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%0A%7C%20%5B%5D%20%3A%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%7C%20%28h%20%3A%3A%20t%29%20%3A%3D%20rev%20t%20%2B%2B%20%5Bh%5D%0A%0Ainductive%20is_in%20%3A%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20Prop%0A%7C%20in_hd%20%7Bx%20%3A%20A%7D%20%7Bl%20%3A%20list%20A%7D%20%3A%20is_in%20x%20%28x%20%3A%3A%20l%29%0A%7C%20in_tl%20%7Bx%20y%20%3A%20A%7D%20%7Bl%20%3A%20list%20A%7D%20%3A%20is_in%20x%20l%20%E2%86%92%20is_in%20x%20%28y%20%3A%3A%20l%29%0Aopen%20is_in%0A%0A---%0A--%20edit%20this%20region%20to%20solve%20the%20challenge%0Atheorem%20is_in_append%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28l1%20l2%20%3A%20list%20A%29%2C%20is_in%20x%20%28l1%20%2B%2B%20l2%29%20%E2%86%94%20is_in%20x%20l1%20%5C%2F%20is_in%20x%20l2%20%3A%3D%20sorry%0Atheorem%20is_in_rev%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28l%20%3A%20list%20A%29%2C%20is_in%20x%20l%20%E2%86%92%20is_in%20x%20%28rev%20l%29%20%3A%3D%20sorry%0A---%0A%0Aexample%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28l1%20l2%20%3A%20list%20A%29%2C%20is_in%20x%20%28l1%20%2B%2B%20l2%29%20%E2%86%94%20is_in%20x%20l1%20%5C%2F%20is_in%20x%20l2%20%3A%3D%20is_in_append%0Aexample%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28l%20%3A%20list%20A%29%2C%20is_in%20x%20l%20%E2%86%92%20is_in%20x%20%28rev%20l%29%20%3A%3D%20is_in_rev%0Aend%20mylist). Your score is the length of the code between the two dashed lines, measured in bytes. The shortest code wins.

#### Tips for beginners

The new beast called "inductive Prop" is a particularly hard concept to grasp. Simply put, a value of `is_in x l` contains a concrete proof that `x` appears in `l`. It is an unknown value, but we can still reason about it:

- Consider all the possible paths `is_in x l` could have been constructed (i.e. proven). This is done with `cases` tactic. When used on a hypothesis of `is_in x l`, it generates two subgoals, one assuming `in_hd` and the other assuming `in_tl`.

  - If you use `cases` on `is_in x []`, there is no way it could have been constructed (since both possibilities result in a cons), the goal is immediately closed by contradiction.
- Apply induction on the proof. It works just like induction on a nat or a list: to prove a theorem in the form of `∀ (x:A) (l:list A), is_in x l → some_prop`, you can prove it by induction on `is_in x l` and prove the "base case" `is_in x (x::l)` and "inductive case" `(is_in x l → some_prop) → is_in x (y::l) → some_prop`.

It takes some practice to see which argument (an inductive data or an inductive prop - in this challenge, `list` or `is_in`) works best with induction for a given statement. You can start by proving parts of the main statement separately as lemmas:

> ```
> lemma is_in_append_l : ∀ (x : A) (l l2 : list A), is_in x l → is_in x (l ++ l2) := sorry
> lemma is_in_append_r : ∀ (x : A) (l l2 : list A), is_in x l → is_in x (l2 ++ l) := sorry
> ```
>
> (Hint: One works best by induction on `l2`, and the other works best on `is_in x l`.)

Answer (score 9):

## Lean, 188 bytes

```
infix`~`:=is_in
def P(x:A)(l m):x~l++m↔x~l\/x~m:=by induction
l;split;repeat{safe[in_hd,in_tl];cases ᾰ<|>cases l_ih.1 ᾰ_ᾰ}def
R(x:A)(l)(i:x~l):x~rev l:=by induction i;safe[P,in_hd]
```

[Try it on Lean Web Editor](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20tactic%0Auniverse%20u%0Avariables%20%7BA%20%3A%20Type%20u%7D%0Anamespace%20mylist%0A%0Ainductive%20list%20%28T%20%3A%20Type%20u%29%20%3A%20Type%20u%0A%7C%20nil%20%3A%20list%0A%7C%20cons%20%3A%20T%20%E2%86%92%20list%20%E2%86%92%20list%0A%0Ainfixr%20%60%20%3A%3A%20%60%3A67%20%3A%3D%20list.cons%0Anotation%20%60%5B%5D%60%20%3A%3D%20list.nil%0Anotation%20%60%5B%60%20l%3A%28foldr%20%60%2C%20%60%20%28h%20t%2C%20list.cons%20h%20t%29%20list.nil%20%60%5D%60%29%20%3A%3D%20l%0A%0Adef%20append%20%3A%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%0A%7C%20%5B%5D%20t%20%3A%3D%20t%0A%7C%20%28h%20%3A%3A%20s%29%20t%20%3A%3D%20h%20%3A%3A%20%28append%20s%20t%29%0Ainstance%20%3A%20has_append%20%28list%20A%29%20%3A%3D%20%E2%9F%A8%40append%20A%E2%9F%A9%0A%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20lemma%20nil_append%20%28s%20%3A%20list%20A%29%20%3A%20%5B%5D%20%2B%2B%20s%20%3D%20s%20%3A%3D%20rfl%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20lemma%20cons_append%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28s%20t%20%3A%20list%20A%29%20%3A%20%28x%20%3A%3A%20s%29%20%2B%2B%20t%20%3D%20x%20%3A%3A%20%28s%20%2B%2B%20t%29%20%3A%3D%20rfl%0A%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20def%20rev%20%3A%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%0A%7C%20%5B%5D%20%3A%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%7C%20%28h%20%3A%3A%20t%29%20%3A%3D%20rev%20t%20%2B%2B%20%5Bh%5D%0A%0Ainductive%20is_in%20%3A%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20Prop%0A%7C%20in_hd%20%7Bx%20%3A%20A%7D%20%7Bl%20%3A%20list%20A%7D%20%3A%20is_in%20x%20%28x%20%3A%3A%20l%29%0A%7C%20in_tl%20%7Bx%20y%20%3A%20A%7D%20%7Bl%20%3A%20list%20A%7D%20%3A%20is_in%20x%20l%20%E2%86%92%20is_in%20x%20%28y%20%3A%3A%20l%29%0Aopen%20is_in%0A%0A---%0Ainfix%60%7E%60%3A%3Dis_in%0Adef%20P%28x%3AA%29%28l%20m%29%3Ax%7El%2B%2Bm%E2%86%94x%7El%5C%2Fx%7Em%3A%3Dby%20induction%0Al%3Bsplit%3Brepeat%7Bsafe%5Bin_hd%2Cin_tl%5D%3Bcases%20%E1%BE%B0%3C%7C%3Ecases%20l_ih.1%20%E1%BE%B0_%E1%BE%B0%7Ddef%0AR%28x%3AA%29%28l%29%28i%3Ax%7El%29%3Ax%7Erev%20l%3A%3Dby%20induction%20i%3Bsafe%5BP%2Cin_hd%5D%0A---%0A%0Aexample%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28l1%20l2%20%3A%20list%20A%29%2C%20is_in%20x%20%28l1%20%2B%2B%20l2%29%20%E2%86%94%20is_in%20x%20l1%20%5C%2F%20is_in%20x%20l2%20%3A%3D%20P%0Aexample%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28l%20%3A%20list%20A%29%2C%20is_in%20x%20l%20%E2%86%92%20is_in%20x%20%28rev%20l%29%20%3A%3D%20R%0Aend%20mylist) (warning: very slow )

Comment: This is my reaction: `ᾰ_ᾰ`

Comment: [208 bytes](https://gist.github.com/kmill/23dbec2b093e404bf6d57dfda420b4e5) using notation, simp attributes, and golfing the proof of `R` further.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't accounting for unicode -- changing disjunction to `\/`, it's 217 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Lean, <s>254</s> <s>226</s> 221 bytes

```
infix`~`:=is_in
variables(x y:A)def D(a):x=y\/x~a↔x~y::a:=by
split;rintro(c|d);safe[in_hd,in_tl]def E:¬x~[].
def P(a b):x~a++b↔x~a\/x~b:=by
induction a;safe[<-D,E]def Q(a)(h:x~a):x~rev a:=by
induction h;safe[in_hd,P]
```

[Try it on the Lean Web Editor](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20tactic%0Auniverse%20u%0Avariables%20%7BA%20%3A%20Type%20u%7D%0Anamespace%20mylist%0A%0Ainductive%20list%20%28T%20%3A%20Type%20u%29%20%3A%20Type%20u%0A%7C%20nil%20%3A%20list%0A%7C%20cons%20%3A%20T%20%E2%86%92%20list%20%E2%86%92%20list%0A%0Ainfixr%20%60%20%3A%3A%20%60%3A67%20%3A%3D%20list.cons%0Anotation%20%60%5B%5D%60%20%3A%3D%20list.nil%0Anotation%20%60%5B%60%20l%3A%28foldr%20%60%2C%20%60%20%28h%20t%2C%20list.cons%20h%20t%29%20list.nil%20%60%5D%60%29%20%3A%3D%20l%0A%0Adef%20append%20%3A%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%0A%7C%20%5B%5D%20t%20%3A%3D%20t%0A%7C%20%28h%20%3A%3A%20s%29%20t%20%3A%3D%20h%20%3A%3A%20%28append%20s%20t%29%0Ainstance%20%3A%20has_append%20%28list%20A%29%20%3A%3D%20%E2%9F%A8%40append%20A%E2%9F%A9%0A%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20lemma%20nil_append%20%28s%20%3A%20list%20A%29%20%3A%20%5B%5D%20%2B%2B%20s%20%3D%20s%20%3A%3D%20rfl%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20lemma%20cons_append%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28s%20t%20%3A%20list%20A%29%20%3A%20%28x%20%3A%3A%20s%29%20%2B%2B%20t%20%3D%20x%20%3A%3A%20%28s%20%2B%2B%20t%29%20%3A%3D%20rfl%0A%0A%40%5Bsimp%5D%20def%20rev%20%3A%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%0A%7C%20%5B%5D%20%3A%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%7C%20%28h%20%3A%3A%20t%29%20%3A%3D%20rev%20t%20%2B%2B%20%5Bh%5D%0A%0Ainductive%20is_in%20%3A%20A%20%E2%86%92%20list%20A%20%E2%86%92%20Prop%0A%7C%20in_hd%20%7Bx%20%3A%20A%7D%20%7Bl%20%3A%20list%20A%7D%20%3A%20is_in%20x%20%28x%20%3A%3A%20l%29%0A%7C%20in_tl%20%7Bx%20y%20%3A%20A%7D%20%7Bl%20%3A%20list%20A%7D%20%3A%20is_in%20x%20l%20%E2%86%92%20is_in%20x%20%28y%20%3A%3A%20l%29%0Aopen%20is_in%0A%0A---%0Ainfix%60%7E%60%3A%3Dis_in%0Avariables%28x%20y%3AA%29def%20D%28a%29%3Ax%3Dy%5C%2Fx%7Ea%E2%86%94x%7Ey%3A%3Aa%3A%3Dby%0Asplit%3Brintro%28c%7Cd%29%3Bsafe%5Bin_hd%2Cin_tl%5Ddef%20E%3A%C2%ACx%7E%5B%5D.%0Adef%20P%28a%20b%29%3Ax%7Ea%2B%2Bb%E2%86%94x%7Ea%5C%2Fx%7Eb%3A%3Dby%0Ainduction%20a%3Bsafe%5B%3C-D%2CE%5Ddef%20Q%28a%29%28h%3Ax%7Ea%29%3Ax%7Erev%20a%3A%3Dby%0Ainduction%20h%3Bsafe%5Bin_hd%2CP%5D%0A---%0A%0Aexample%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28l1%20l2%20%3A%20list%20A%29%2C%20is_in%20x%20%28l1%20%2B%2B%20l2%29%20%E2%86%94%20is_in%20x%20l1%20%5C%2F%20is_in%20x%20l2%20%3A%3D%20P%0Aexample%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20%28x%20%3A%20A%29%20%28l%20%3A%20list%20A%29%2C%20is_in%20x%20l%20%E2%86%92%20is_in%20x%20%28rev%20l%29%20%3A%3D%20Q%0Aend%20mylist)

`P` and `Q` are the desired theorems.  I reuse the `~` notation (which is normally for the `list.perm` relation) to mean the `is_in` relation, which lets us save a lot of spaces in lemma statements.

I was going for "readable" and fast-to-typecheck (Anders isn't kidding about their solution being slow!).  `D` is a definition lemma for `is_in` (mathlib calls the reversed version of it [`list.mem_cons_iff`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/data/list/lemmas.html#list.mem_cons_iff); I had to reverse it to trick Lean into disambiguating `::` correctly).  The `E` lemma uses the equation compiler to automatically construct a proof (mathlib calls it [`list.not_mem_nil`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/data/list/lemmas.html#list.not_mem_nil)).

Some of these tricks can shorten Anders's first solution to 217 bytes:

```
infix`~`:=is_in
attribute[simp]in_hd in_tl
def P(x:A)(l m):x~l++m↔x~l\/x~m:=by induction l;split;intro;repeat{finish<|>cases
ᾰ<|>cases l_ih.1 ᾰ_ᾰ}def R(x:A)(l)(i:x~l):x~rev l:=by induction i;simp[P];left;tauto
```

---

I want to mention that `is_in` might more conventionally be given as a recursive definition:

```
def is_in (x : A) : Π (l : list A), Prop
| [] := false
| (y::ys) := x = y ∨ is_in ys
```

Given this, there is a 150 byte solution:

```
infix`~`:=is_in
def P(x:A)(l m):x~l++m↔x~l\/x~m:=by
induction l;split;simp!;intro;safe
def Q(x:A)(l)(i:x~l):x~rev l:=by induction l;simp![P]at*;safe
```

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Thanks. I was using 3.23.0 and a mathlib from November, and I seem to remember `::` was changed in the meantime (it used to be much more overloaded).  Now that I'm back at a more powerful computer, I shortened it more and got it working in the web editor.

Comment: `def E(x:A):` → `def E:`

Comment: @AndersKaseorg 